# Is LXDE/Lubuntu under active development?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

I got [here](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/388#issuecomment-19149012) a comment that LXDE is somehow "deprecated", not actively developed, entailing that the problems some programs may have in LXDE (qBittorrent, in the case of the linked comment)  should be dismissed on that basis.

What is the situation?

Comment: whether LXDE is developed or not is a matter of fact that myself cannot state. please comment on the problem you see with this question if you down-vote it, or else consider voting to close - like [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/84373/47206) was - instead of down-voting. it is a matter of great importance for ubuntu users whether the desktop environment of one of its 'flavors' is actively developed. only that the best place to discuss may not be here

Comment: People downvote for whatever reason they want. You only got one. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @Seth :) they may down-vote, and i may comment asking them to comment. in fact i am not sure this is a good question, as it was created in reaction to an untrustworthy opinion, and that's why i was  asking for comments, to find whether i should keep it or not. i even flagged it to close

Comment: @cipricus, I agree with you that this question isn't "Ask Ubuntu" material. I'm not sure that a comment on the internet justifies a question on Ask Ubuntu :). I'm sure you could have researched this quite easily and found out whether LXDE/Lubuntu is living/dying/dead.

Comment: @vasa1 - very true. will not happen again :) should i delete it, or wait to close?

Comment: All I can say is that I added my vote to close :)

Comment: @vasa1 - that's that then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding this correctly.  I don't know if that info is true, because LXDE is very much alive.  I don't see any information on the [LXDE](http://lxde.org/) site that indicates that.

Even [Lubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) is very much alive.

On both sites I don't see anything substantiating that note.

For the PCManFM changelog, you can find out about the changes [Here](http://blog.lxde.org/?tag=pcmanfm) and [Here](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/x11-misc/pcmanfm/ChangeLog?view=markup)

For the LXPanel changelog, you can find out about the changes [Here](http://blog.lxde.org/?p=931) and [Here](http://sources.gentoo.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/gentoo-x86/lxde-base/lxpanel/ChangeLog?view=markup)

And for other components of LXDE visit the [About](http://lxde.org/lxde) page on the LXDE site

As per cipricus comment, and I agree with it, "**that info is not true, because LXDE is very much alive**"

---

LXDE Mailing list: http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=lxde-list

Comment: you should probably say: "that info is **not** true, because LXDE is very much alive"

Answer (score 1):

Rumours of LXDE's death are greatly exaggerated.

It's still being maintained, and the core parts of it are still actively being developed.